# Displaying image from HBase in SpotFire

Tags: hbase, etl, spotfire

I've converted my images and stored on HBase as Bytes.
Now i want to SpotFire to read the Image (as Bytes) from hbase and display it.
I understand that i can use Phoenix connector to connect to HBase from SpotFire, but how can i render images(which are stored as Bytes in HBase) in SpotFire?

Answer (score 1):

I will ignore the HBase connection part of the question as you already have the Phoenix connector as an answer to that.

So more specifically about how to display images in Spotfire:

- Spotfire properties can hold Binary values
- Images if converted to Binary values can be stored in Document properties
- If a binary document property is displayed in text area as 'label', the underlying image is displayed.